# Thread Breakpoint?

Tags: c++, if-statement

This loop is supposed to prompt the user for values from 1 to 6 until it has 5 values. It works for every other number, but if I enter a 2 it says "Thread1: breakpoint 1.1" then doesn't crash but stops accepting inputs.
I am new to C++ so I may be missing something obvious syntax-wise.

```
 int userInput = 0;
 int numUserIns = 0;
 int diceRoll1, diceRoll3, diceRoll2, diceRoll4, diceRoll5, diceRoll6;

 int numOnes = 0;
 int numTwos = 0;
 int numThrees = 0;
 int numFours = 0;
 int numFives = 0;
 int numSix = 0;

while (numUserIns <= 5){
    cout << "Enter a number from 1 to 6\n";
    cin >> userInput;
    if (userInput == 1){
        diceRoll1 = userInput;
        numUserIns++;
        numOnes++;
    } else if (userInput == 2){ //not accepting two as input
        diceRoll2 = userInput;  //This line causes error: Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1
        numUserIns++;
        numTwos++;
    } else if (userInput == 3){
        diceRoll3 = userInput;
        numUserIns++;
        numThrees++;
    } else if (userInput == 4){
        diceRoll4 = userInput;
        numUserIns++;
        numFours++;
    } else if (userInput == 5){
        diceRoll5 = userInput;
        numUserIns++;
        numFives++;
    } else if (userInput == 6){
        diceRoll6 = userInput;
        numUserIns++;
        numSix++;
    } else if (userInput < 1 || userInput > 6){
        cout << "invalid input";
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `int diceRoll1, diceRoll3, diceRoll2, diceRoll4, diceRoll5, diceRoll6;` suggests you really want an array: `int diceRoll[6];` This, and doing the same with `numOnes` through `numSix` will dramaitcally reduce the amount of code you need. The `if`/ `else if` block turns into `diceRoll[userInput -1]= userInput; numUserIns++; nums[userInput -1]++;`  This also exposes that `diceRoll[userInput -1]= userInput;` is utterly pointless (the number contained is always the index + 1) so `diceRoll` can be discarded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're triggering a [breakpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint) in your code. This means that your IDE is stopping the code in execution so you can look at the state of variable and the like at that step in the code. Most IDEs will have a dot or arrow on the left you can click on to turn breakpoints on and off. Otherwise, look up how to turn off breakpoints for the IDE you are using.

Comment: That was it! Thanks.